# Can we run android emulator without VTx enabled processor?

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, expo, react-native-cli

I have hp laptop with intel pentium 987 1.5Ghz running on windows 10pro. I want to run android emulator fro react-native-cli. When i created virtual device in android studio {API 26} it says your processor does not support VTx virtualization.

**Does that means i can not run react-native-cli apps  ?**

**And the only option is that to use expo ?**

**Is there any alternative ?**